# Not able to read sensor data from Cloudant NoSQL db using the sync-android library

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, iot, cloudant, nosql

I'm not able fetch sensor data uploaded to a Cloudant NoSQL DB through the IoT Platform using the sync-android library for some reason.

Please find the code, the error message and the line where the error is occurring below:

```
try {
    uri = new URI("https://user:password@somehost.cloudant.com/database");
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    ds = manager.openDatastore("my_datastores");
} catch (DatastoreNotCreatedException e) {

            }
Replicator replicator = ReplicatorBuilder.pull().from(uri).to(ds).build();
Log.e("aaaaa",String.valueOf(replicator));
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
Listener listener = new Listener(latch);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(listener),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
replicator.getEventBus().register(listener);
replicator.start();
try {
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
replicator.getEventBus().unregister(listener);
if (replicator.getState() != Replicator.State.COMPLETE) {
    System.out.println("Error replicating FROM remote");
    System.out.println(listener.error);
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.cloudant.sync.datastore.Datastore com.cloudant.sync.datastore.DatastoreManager.openDatastore(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.imb_bng_04.cloudserver.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
```

error in line:
   ds = manager.openDatastore("my_datastores");

Comment: I removed the credentials from the URL. Make sure you do that yourself in future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like maybe you are getting null pointer because you did not initialize an object.  See this S[tack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329029/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-view-v) which has similar error.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
```

something was null

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method
  'com.cloudant.sync.datastore.Datastore com.cloudant.sync.datastore.DatastoreManager
  ...openDatastore(java.lang.String)'
on a null object reference
```

so the thing that was null was the object you called `openDatastore` on

```
at com.example.imb_bng_04.cloudserver.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
```

on this particular line:

```
ds = manager.openDatastore("my_datastores");
```

So, what is this object reference, on which we called `openDatastore`, and which turned out to be null?

It was `manager`, very obviously. The variable `manager` is null. You haven't shown where it comes from, so no-one can possibly help tell you *why* it is null, but your fix consists of figuring that out, initializing it to something sensible, and then not calling methods on a null object reference.